# How to deploy with non-minified codes app on Heroku?

Tags: node.js, meteor, heroku, angular, angular2-meteor

I have an **angular2-meteor** app. Because of Angular2's [this bug](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/6380), after deployment, it cannot run well. This bug only happens with **minified** codes.

So how can I deploy with **non-minified** codes on Heroku?

I tried

`heroku config:set NODE_ENV=dev`

`heroku config:set NODE_ENV=development`

`heroku config:set NODE_ENV=debug`

But seems like the code still minified. Still shows same error.

Thanks

Comment: Try disabling mangling on uglify

Answer (score 0):

The minification takes place in meteors build system, if you're building and deploying, that's where the minification is happening.  One way to avoid this would be to use the assets API, and include the scripts you don't want minified (via a package) using the `Assets.addAssets()`.

But I wouldn't recommend this.

If you absolutely need to run it un-minified for debugging, we loaded the whole dev environment onto a Digital Ocean server, but this should only be for debugging and not production.

Unfortunately the only thing I would recommend is that you wait for Angular 2 to be production ready, out of BETA with kinks like this ironed out.

Comment: thanks @pushplaybang, I ran `meteor remove standard-minifiers` first, then the program can runs well using `meteor --production` locally.
But once I deployed on heroku, it still shows `EXCEPTION: No Directive annotation found on e`

Comment: yeah I would expect errors if you're removing that.   I wouldn't recommend it.